# How do I disable the grey text by close braces?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013, when the opening brace is off-screen, a grey link appears next to the closing brace as in this image:

[image]

Where can I find the option to disable this? I'm not sure what the feature is called so can't Google it!

(I have ReSharper installed so it could be that as well. Not sure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't ReSharper, this feature belongs to VSCommands, it's called [Code Block End Tagger](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Features-CodeBlockEndTagger). You can turn it off in VSCommand options somewhere.